# Trying to vectorizaion of gray scale image from bottelneck layer

Tags: python, autoencoder

i am working on program that make a vectorization for gray scale images not RGB that taken bottleneck layer from autoencoder  but i have the following error, any suggestion:

Root: image at /path/to/images is not RGB , therefore not using it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We might be able to help you better if you provide some examples of what you've already tried. Please edit your question to include the section of code producing this error. At first glance, it seems your image is not RGB?

Comment: Thanks J.Blackader.i am using grayscale images -ultrasound- the following code used:

Comment: # imports
import argparse
import logging
import os

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import xrange
from tqdm import tqdm

from autoencoder_training import build_model
from utils import configs
from utils.ops import get_pkl_file
from utils.ops import 

from utils.vector_file_handler import VectorSaver
from utils.vector_file_handler import establish_vectors_folder

# setup
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# variables
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Program to vectorize ' \

Comment: Do not post code in the comments, when you can edit your question.